# No me toma una variable (SASS) proveniente de otro archivo SCSS

Tags: html5, css3, sass, scss, importación

Muy buenas. Tengo un problema a la hora de utilizar una variable en un archivo **sass** proveniente de otro. Cabe aclarar que no es importado explícitamente en el dicho primer archivo.

Debido a que practico la metodología **SMACSS** es importante la buena organización de los archivos en diferentes carpetas. Debido a esto, importe cada archivo a un único **.scss**, que se sincroniza a un **.css** principal.

Al usar una variable me dice que esta está **indefinida**, por lo tanto la compilación se detiene. Aunque por otro lado, al importar el archivo que almacena dicha variable al .scss que la utiliza, esta es tomada con normalidad.
Esto ultimo no es una solución, ya que rompería la metodología usada (creería).

Me gustaría saber si esto es un error en como importo los archivos o si no es posible realizar la problemática en cuestión.

**Estructura de archivos**

[image: estructura de archivos]

**Archivo principal .scss**

[image: Main.scss]

**Archivo donde es importada la variable**

[image: Header.scss]

En esta última imagen el import de la primer línea no deberia ir.
Si es eliminada sale este error en consola:

[image: Error]

Comment: Recuerda agregar tu código como texto en lugar de imágenes del mismo.

Comment: Es por que estas importando primero toda la carpeta de `layouts` y mas abajo el de `utilities` y al momento de usar la variable de utilities en layout no la reconoce, pon la importación de `utilities` antes de `layouts` y con eso evitarías importarlo en el `header.scss`

Answer (score 1):

En el scss donde uses la variable, definela al principio añadiendo !default, asi:

`$color-primary: #000 !default;`

De esta forma tendra un color por defecto si no es definida y no te dara error.